# How to choose the best splitting attribute with same gain information

Tags: r, attributes, split, cart-analysis

I am actually computing step by step how CART (Classification and regression trees) choose the best attribute split with this training data set:

```
      Car Age Children Location
1   sedan  23        0      yes
2  sports  31        1       no
3   sedan  36        1       no
4   truck  25        2       no
5  sports  30        0       no
6   sedan  36        0       no
7   sedan  25        0      yes
8   truck  36        1       no
9   sedan  30        2      yes
10  sedan  31        1      yes
11 sports  25        0       no
12  truck  45        0      yes
```

Results given by R:

- n= 12 

  node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
        * denotes terminal node
- 1) root 12 5 no (0.5833333 0.4166667)
- 2) Car=sports,truck 6 1 no (0.8333333 0.1666667)
- 4) Age

  5) Age>=40.5 1 0 yes (0.0000000 1.0000000) *

  3) Car=sedan 6 2 yes (0.3333333 0.6666667)

  6) Age>=33.5 2 0 no (1.0000000 0.0000000) *

  7) Age

For the root node Gini(root)=0.486

- - with the Car attribute GainGini(Car)=0.1255;
- - with the Age attribute I got the same gain with threshold 27.5 and 33.5. So which one to choose if GainGini(Age) will be maximized.
- - with the Children attribute. the 2 child nodes are very pure so GainGini(Children)=0.486

My first question is why on this plot I got the Car attribute for the splitting?

  For the first right child node:Gini(node2)=0.444
- - with the Age attribute: threshold 33.5 got GainGini(Age)=0.444
- -with the children attribute: same as the root node (all instances are pure) GainGini(children)=0.444

this is my second question how CART manage to choose the split attribute with those 2 values?

Comment: I think Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask that.

Comment: I don't see any code. Wouldn't we need to know the package and the code in order to address your confusion?

Comment: How are you calculating Gini?

Comment: I use rpart package.and for gini computing gini=1-(square(p1)+square(p2) GainGini(split)=gini(parent)-((n1/n)gini(child1)+(n2/n)gini(child2))